# Android - switching from an activity to a list activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, listactivity

I am new to android programming and was wondering how to start a listactivity from an activity using intents.

I have defined my class as an activity in the android manifest file and included a listview in my listactivity in the xml file.

Whenever I click on my button to start my listactivity i get the error message "Unfortunately, main activity has stopped".

When my class extends activity (rather than listactivity), the application works but then I am unable to use a listAdapter which I need.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
   Button timedevents = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
   timedevents.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
   public void onClick(View v) {            
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimedEvents.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
   }
```

Thankyou for taking the time to help,
Kind Regards,
Jamie

Answer (score 1):

Go through the example here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

probably the error is coming because you are not using the id of the list view which a list Activity require `@android:id/list"` For example the xml file at the above link has :

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

     <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#FF0000"
               android:text="No data"/>
```

In short,You must use `"@android:id/list"` and `"@android:id/empty"`

Comment: thankyou, i tried this but it still has the same error message.

Comment: could the problem be that i am trying to start a listactivity and not an activity when using my intent or would that not make a difference?